# Excel VBA type mismatch - Public Object

Tags: excel, vba, type-mismatch

I am trying to read a global public Object **foo**. I declared it in one module and want to read it in every other module. Why do I get a type mismatch error?

Modul1:

```
Public Sub Test()
    If foo Is Nothing Then MsgBox "Foo is not initialized", vbOKOnly
End Sub
```

foo:

```
Public foo As Object
```

[image: VBA Screenshot]

Comment: Because you have a module with that name? :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What's happening is a phenomenon called *identifier shadowing*: the public variable `foo` exists in the same scope as the module `foo`.

And since `Sub Test` doesn't exist in the same module as the `foo` variable, the identifier `foo` in `Modul1` resolves to the module `foo`, because it *syntactically* can: the *syntax* does not differentiate between a standard module and a class module with a `VB_PredeclaredId` attribute, so this:

```
If Foo Is Nothing Then
```

Is *syntactically* no different than:

```
If UserForm1 Is Nothing Then
```

Or:

```
If ThisWorkbook Is Nothing Then
```

VBA will always try to resolve an in-scope identifier to a module if a module exists by that name... unless it's a class module *without* a `VB_PredeclaredId` attribute, in which case it knows you can't possibly be referring to the class itself (a class is a *type*, not an *object*). Arguably VBA should be smart enough to also know that a standard module isn't an object either, but I wouldn't hold my breath for a fix ;-)

---

[Rubberduck](http://www.github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck) (disclaimer: I'm heavily involved in this open-source project) can shed more light about what's resolving to what:

[image: context-sensitive selection shows what 'Foo' is resolving to]

You can use the `Foo` (the module) as a qualifier for `Foo` (the variable) to fix the compile error:

```
If Foo.Foo Is Nothing Then
```

This is now unambiguous, because now `Foo.Foo` is clearly referring to the member `Foo` of the module `Foo`.

Another (perhaps better) solution, would be to rename either the module or the variable.

Comment: ...or simply rename the module to `fooModule`. Excellent explanation.